# Ошибка при создании формы регистрации

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь сделать форму регистрации на сайте, но получаю ошибку.

```js
var capkeygoogle;

function CheckForm() {
  var pass1 = document.forms[0].password.value;
  var pass2 = document.forms[0].password2.value;
  var login = document.forms[0].login.value;
  var email = document.forms[0].email.value;
  var checkbox1 = document.getElementById('checkbox');
  if (!(document.getElementById('login').checkValidity())) {
    $('.alert').css('background', 'red');
    Alert_Opoveshenie('Login is incorrect!');
    return false
  }
  if (!(document.getElementById('email').checkValidity())) {
    $('.alert').css('background', 'red');
    Alert_Opoveshenie('E-mail is incorrect!');
    return false
  }
  if (!(document.getElementById('password').checkValidity())) {
    $('.alert').css('background', 'red');
    Alert_Opoveshenie('Password №1 is incorrect!');
    return false
  }
  if (!(document.getElementById('password2').checkValidity())) {
    $('.alert').css('background', 'red');
    Alert_Opoveshenie('Password №2 is incorrect!');
    return false
  }
  if (pass1 != pass2) {
    $('.alert').css('background', 'red');
    Alert_Opoveshenie('Password mismatch!');
    return false
  }


  $.ajax({
    url: 'Registration.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      login: login,
      password: pass1,
      email: email,
      capkeygoogle: capkeygoogle
    },
    success: function(res) {
      if (res.color == 'green') {
        document.location.href = "";
        return true
      } else {
        $('.alert').css('background', res.color);
        Alert_Opoveshenie(res.message);
        return false
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      $('.alert').css('background', 'red');
      Alert_Opoveshenie('Error!');
      return false
    }
  });
}

function mySuperFunction(captchaKey) {
  capkeygoogle = captchaKey;
}

function Alert_Opoveshenie(Text) {
  document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = Text;
  $('.alert').animate({
    bottom: '10px',
    opacity: '1'
  }, 1000, function() {
    // После показа убираем его
    var alertHide = setInterval(function() {
      $('.alert').animate({
        bottom: '-100%',
        opacity: '0'
      }, 1000);
      clearInterval(alertHide);
    }, 2000); // Время "жизни" алерта 2 секунды.
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="login__input" name="login" id="login" placeholder="Username" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{5,20}$" title="LOGIN can consist of 5 (five) to 20 (twenty) characters from: English characters (lower case), numbers and signs - (dot), (dash), (bottom_incident)"
    autocomplete="off">
  <input type="email" class="login__input" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
  <input type="password" class="login__input" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required pattern="(?=(.*[0-9]))(?=.*[a-zа-я])(?=(.*[A-ZА-Я]))(?=(.*)).{6,20}" title="The password can consist of 6 (six) to 20 (twenty) characters, you must have at least one digit, one capital letter, one small letter">
  <input type="password" class="login__input" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Repeat Password" required pattern="(?=(.*[0-9]))(?=.*[a-zа-я])(?=(.*[A-ZА-Я]))(?=(.*)).{6,20}" title="The password can consist of 6 (six) to 20 (twenty) characters, you must have at least one digit, one capital letter, one small letter">
  <input type="button" name="reg" id="registration" value="Register" onclick="CheckForm();">
</form>
<div class="alert" id="alert">Оповещение</div>
```

Ошибка:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined
>           at CheckForm

Comment: Может кто помочь?

Comment: Где у вас элемент `id=alert`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko не скопировалось, добавил в конец html

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko подскажете?

Comment: В приведенном вами коде нет ошибок. В чем вопрос?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko так откуда тогда ошибка при нажатии на кнопку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined at CheckForm

Comment: В приведенном коде при нажатии на кнопку ошибок нет.